# How to install android market on emulator for all api's

Tags: java, android, emulation, google-play

How can I install android market and other apk's on the android emulator. I tried some solutions, but they don't seem to work, or are unclear.

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the person above says, it is not available, but you could extract the apk from the file explorer.

I used this method to install market on api 4 and 8:

> If you are using windows, change the "/" to "\" and just type
>   "android" instead of "./android"

```
1) go to android sdk path and create a new machine:
    * type this in terminal:
        cd "/home/<username>/.eclipse/android-sdk/tools"
    * then this  
        ./android
    * then click on Tools -> Manage AVDs...
    * create a new machine

2) start the machine and set the partition size
    * go to this path:
        cd "/home/<username>/.eclipse/android-sdk/tools"
    * open the machine (keep the terminal open)
        ./emulator @<machine name> -partition-size 96

3) modify some files, root and install apps
    * go to this path:
        cd "/home/<username>/.eclipse/android-sdk/platform-tools"
    * pull the 'build.prop' file in the platform-tools folder
        ./adb pull /system/build.prop
    * remove this line: 'ro.config.nocheckin=yes' and save
    * mount the partition to that we can write to it
        ./adb remount
    * replace the edited file
        ./adb push build.prop /system/build.prop
    * install the apps
        ./adb install "/home/<username>/Emulator files/GoogleServicesFramework.apk"
        ./adb install "/home/<username>/Emulator files/Gmail.apk"
        ./adb install "/home/<username>/Emulator files/Vending.apk"

4) root the phone
    * go to this path:
        cd "/home/<username>/.eclipse/android-sdk/platform-tools"   
    * mout system files
        ./adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system 
    * put script for su in system
        ./adb push "/home/<username>/Emulator files/su" /system/xbin/su
    * make system folder writeble
        ./adb shell chmod 06755 /system
        ./adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
    * install super user app to manage permissions
        ./adb install superuser.apk 

5) if apps are not showing in the market:
    * go to applications -> manage applications in the emulator
    * click on google services framework -> force stop and delete cache 
    * click on market -> force stop and delete data + cache
    * restart device
```

Comment: Please do not advocate copyright infringement on StackOverflow.

Comment: We don't enforce other people's copyrights.  However, going to some sketchy 3rd party website to download binaries seems like a foolish thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Market is not available for the emulator. It is only available under license from Google for distribution on hardware.