# How to install android market on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I try to install android market on emulator using these instructions - [How to install android market on emulator for all api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606186/how-to-install-android-market-on-emulator-for-all-apis), but after restarting emulator all changes are lost.

[In other guide](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html), I read that I need to remove some .img files from device avd folder, but it doesn't work. What else can I do to permanently install market to emulator?

Comment: You'll need to use snapshots. See [this link](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/snapshots-and-the-new-android-avd-manager/) or google for "AVD snapshot."

Comment: Have you tried this??
http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

Comment: You can dowload this latest Play Store APK : [download](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90690956/com.android.vending.8014017.apk) After downloading just install it as usual.

Comment: The Play Store (a.k.a., Android Market) is not available for the emulator. It is only available for licensed device manufacturers. Please do not pirate software, as is proposed in the current answers on this question.

Comment: What's the purpose? Does your app crash on the emulator because you want to refer the user to the store - or do you want to get apps?

Comment: @Satheesh - I wrote that I tried that solution.

Comment: @323go - I read that, but I can't make the snapshot because that radiobuttons are disabled, and idon't know why.

Comment: @ChrisConway - I need market on emulator for test purpose - i have two apps, free and paid, and I need to test how the paid app page in market opens from the free app. Currently it crashes on exception if market not installed.

Comment: @kruz05 Sorry i dint notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you told me you need this for test-purpose, I think it isn't worth the trouble. Don't you know any person with an Android device to test it? I know this isn't the answer you expect - but as it is recommended to test on a real device anyhow - here my suggestion:

I've been using this code in a few apps which are in the market and it works fine:

```
public static void goToMarket(Context context){
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    it.setData(Uri.parse(context.getString(R.string.playstorelink)));
    context.startActivity(it);
}
```

The link in the string could look like this: market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

To prevent this code from crashing on the emulator (obviously there is no PlayStore) you can wrap this code in a try catch blog:

```
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for piece of code. One of the problem was find valid form of uri for market, and I was find it trough some test iterations on emalator. Also, if open market fails, I added some code to open market trough http.

Comment: Code:
    
    try {
        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + googlePlayAppName) );
        gameActivity.startActivity(marketIntent);    
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + googlePlayAppName));
            gameActivity.startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }                   
    catch (Exception e){}