# android market app is not available list of default applications

Tags: android

I am trying to run android on emulator. I could not find "android market" app in the default app list of the emulator. I tried to download that from google play but it requires you to have "google play app" in the default list, which is also not available in my emulator. Then I tried to search for downloading the apk file for "android market" on net, so that I could install it. But I could not find some reliable source for downloading that.

If you could suggest me some good way of installing this app, I would be really thankful to you. Please also tell me some good download link for downloading android apps.

Comment: duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606186/how-to-install-android-market-on-emulator-for-all-apis

Comment: I am really sorry that my question got repeated. Believe me I tried to search net for around 2 hours. So somehow I could not find this thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know that .apk files can't be downloaded from google play. Those files are always installed directly to the supportive device. Secondly Emulator can't have play store app.

So, If you want to install the .apk files on emulator, first download .apk from torrent(famous .apk files are available there) then use adb tool to push .apk file on emulator. just google "how to install apk on emulator" you will find many option use adb push to emulator.

May this helps you, Enjoy android on Emulator. :)